# Want to delete multiple tags with same tag name in XML using python elementtree?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am new to Python, As per project requirement i want to launch web request for diffrent test cases. lets say (Refer below Employee_req.xml) for one test case i want to launch web services with all organizations. but for another one i want to launch web services in which all first-name tags should be removed.I am using ElementTree in python for dealing with XML. Please find below code segment.Modification of tag and attribute values works fine without any issue. but while removing certain tags it was throwing error. I am not correct with Xpath so will you please suggest possible ways?

Emp_req.xml

```
<request>
    <orgaqnization>
        <name>org1</name>
        <employee>
            <first-name>abc</first-name>
            <last-name>def</last-name>
            <dob>19870909</dob>
        </employee>
    </orgaqnization>
    <orgaqnization>
        <name>org2</name>
        <employee>
            <first-name>abc2</first-name>
            <last-name>def2</last-name>
            <dob>19870909</dob>
        </employee>
    </orgaqnization>
    <orgaqnization>
        <name>org3</name>
        <employee>
            <first-name>abc3</first-name>
            <last-name>def3</last-name>
            <dob>19870909</dob>
        </employee>
    </orgaqnization>
</request>
```

Python:: Test.py

```
modify_query("Remove",tag_name=".//first-name")
import xml.etree.ElementTree as query_xml
def modifiy_query(self,*args,**kwargs):   
        root = query_tree.getroot()         
        operation_type=args[0]
        tag_name=kwargs['tagname'] 
        try:              
            if operation_type=="Remove":    
                logger.info("Removing %s Tag from XML" % tag_name)
                root.remove(tag_name)               
            elif operation_type=="Insert":                        
                logger.info("Inserting %s tag to xml" % tag_name)
            else:
                raise InvalidXMLOperationError("Operation " + operation_type + " is invalid")
        except InvalidXMLOperationError,e:
            logger.error("Invalid XML operation %s" % operation_type)

The error message (Flow could be differ because i am running this code from some other program):

    File "Test.py", line 161, in <module> testsuite.scheduler() 
    File "Test.py", line 91, in scheduler self.launched_query_with("Without_date_range") 
    File "Test.py", line 55, in launched_query_with test.modifiy_query("Remove",tagname='.//first-name') 
    File "/home/XXX/YYYY/common.py", line 287, in modifiy_query parent.remove(child) 
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 337, in remove self._children.remove(element) 
    ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Thanks,

Priyank Shah

Comment: Could you provide the error message ?

Comment: it was ValueError: ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: It would be easier if you pasted the whole message in your question.

Comment: `File "Test.py", line 161, in <module>
      testsuite.scheduler()
      File "Test.py", line 91, in scheduler
       self.launched_query_with("Without_date_range")
      File "Test.py", line 55, in launched_query_with
      test.modifiy_query("Remove",tagname='.//dateRange')
      File "/home/XXX/YYYY/common.py", line 287, in modifiy_query
       parent.remove(child)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line    337, in remove
      self._children.remove(element)
      ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`

Comment: I resolve this By doing this:: `tag_name=kwargs['tagname']
                            logger.info("Removing %s Tag from XML" % tag_name) 
                            parentlist=root.findall(".//*")
                            for parent in parentlist:                                
                                child=parent.find(tag_name)
                                if child is not None:
                                    parent.remove(child) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`remove` takes an element as parameter, not a xpath.

Instead of:

```
root.remove(tag_name)
```

you should have:

```
elements = root.findall(tag_name)
for element in elements:
    root.remove(element)
```

Comment: This is still not working. below is the code which i did: I am calling this function like  :: Test.modifiy_query("Remove",tagname='first-name') `tag_name=kwargs['tagname']
                            logger.info("Removing %s Tag from XML" % tag_name) 
                            childnodes=root.findall(tag_name)
                            print len(childnodes)
                            for child in childnodes:
                                root.remove(child)`

Comment: Thanks morphyn.. i resolve this by tweaking logic: thanks for your time... `tag_name=kwargs['tagname']
                            logger.info("Removing %s Tag from XML" % tag_name) 
                            parentlist=root.findall(".//*")
                            for parent in parentlist:                                
                                child=parent.find(tag_name)
                                if child is not None:
                                    parent.remove(child)`